# Purpose of NYET packet in USB 2.0 HS when same purpose is accomplished by NAK

Tags: usb, peripherals

[Depiction of state transitions with NYET, NAK and PING packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h43v5.png)

What special purpose does NYET serve when the next transaction could be simply be avoided by a NAK packet from the device?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the introduction of the NYET handshake packet were bandwidth utilization efficiency considerations.

If a device responds with a NYET, the host knows that the device will very likely NAK the next OUT transaction which means that the whole frame time the data is being transmitted is wasted: The exact same data will have to be sent again.

That's why NAKing an OUT transaction wastes a lot of frame time since the OUT transaction occupies the bus without purpose and it competes with other transactions/devices as well, taking frame time from them.

Imagine the protocol without the NYET handshake: The host would have to send the same whole block of data (i.e. up to 512 bytes for bulk endpoints) every time the device NAKs just to inquiry if the device is ready.

If the host gets a NYET instead, it will start PINGing the device, asking if the device is ready to receive more data. A PING transaction is very short compared to a large data OUT transaction. Hence, if the device NAKs the PING, the host can use the rest of the frame for other transactions instead which leads to better utilization of the bus.